# Stacking Drawing Matrix for SpriteBatch in XNA

Tags: xna, 2d, matrix, spritebatch

I'm trying to make a 2D engine for XNA with SpriteBatch. My `object unit` is `Entity`, which can include other `Entities` as its children. However, when drawing them, the rotation and scaling stacking do not work well.

Here is my Entity code:

```
    protected virtual void PreDraw(Engine pEngine)
    {
        pEngine.PushMatrix();

        { // Transform Matrix
            // Translate
            pEngine.DrawingMatrix *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(this.X, this.Y, 0);

            { // Scale
                float translateX = this.ScaleCenterY + this.X;
                float translateY = this.ScaleCenterX + this.Y;

                pEngine.DrawingMatrix *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(-translateX, -translateY, 0);
                pEngine.DrawingMatrix *= Matrix.CreateScale(this.ScaleX, this.ScaleY, 0);
                pEngine.DrawingMatrix *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(translateX, translateY, 0);
            }

            { // Rotation
                float translateX = this.RotationCenterX + this.X;
                float translateY = this.RotationCenterY + this.Y;

                pEngine.DrawingMatrix *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(-translateX, -translateY, 0);
                pEngine.DrawingMatrix *= Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(this.Rotation));
                pEngine.DrawingMatrix *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(translateX, translateY, 0);
            }
        }

    }

    protected virtual void Draw(Engine pEngine) { }

    protected virtual void PostDraw(Engine pEngine)
    {
        pEngine.PopMatrix();
    }
```

I will implement some primitive entities by overridding Draw method. Here is my Drawing call, and the `Draw` implementation for Rectangle, and the `StartDrawing` in the Engine:

**Managed Draw call every drawing**:

```
    public void ManagedDraw(Engine pEngine)
    {
        if (!this.Visible) return;



        { // Perform Drawing
            this.PreDraw(pEngine);

            int childIndex = 0;

            // Underlay Children
            while (childIndex < this.Children.Count && this.Children[childIndex].Z < 0)
            {
                this.Children[childIndex].ManagedDraw(pEngine);
                childIndex++;
            }

            // Draw Self
            this.Draw(pEngine);

            // Overlay Children
            for (; childIndex < this.Children.Count; childIndex++)
            {
                this.Children[childIndex].ManagedDraw(pEngine);
            }

            this.PostDraw(pEngine);
        }

    }
```

** Draw implementation of Rectable**:

```
    protected override void Draw(Engine pEngine)
    {
        pEngine.StartDrawing();
        pEngine.SpriteBatch.Draw(pEngine.RectangleTexture, new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)this.Width, (int)this.Height), new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1), this.Color);
        pEngine.StopDrawing();
    }
```

**Start Drawing of Engine**:

```
    public void StartDrawing()
    {
        this.SpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.LinearClamp, DepthStencilState.None, null, null, this.DrawingMatrix);
    }
```

Here is one example of my failure, where the parent has Rotation of 30, while the children has none, but it should be in the center of the parent (red) rectangle:
[image]

Please give me the problem with above Drawing Matrix. What should I do to achieve the stacking?

Comment: AFAIK, this matrix you puts in the spriteBatch.Begin call represents the final Camera/View of the renderization. It doesn't make much sense to stack matrices in there, because the renderization generates only one final image. Individual rotations of sprites should be applied in the spriteBatch.Draw call.

Comment: So can you suggest me any alternative? I would like the transformation of the children inherited by the parent entity. For example, the child is right at the center of the parent, when the parent entity rotation is 30, the child also rotate, but still at parent's center? An example is Unity's game objects, and AndEngine entities.

Comment: Hum... Now I understood what you want! I'd simply put a reference of the parent in the child, and the child would apply the Rotation of its parent over its own Rotation.